# Using OpenId, Google or Facebook Login to allow users to create an account on a site

Tags: authentication

Can OpenId, Google and Facebook Login be used to allow a user to create an account on my site (rather than just sign in).

This way, I feel I would not have to go through the additional step of verifying accounts.

I need to store a users email and username on my site, so he can login later. Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Say for an example, you can use facebook. Facebook has already verified a user. So, when this user will come to your site with their facebook id you can easily verify them. To do it you have to use facebook api. This api will inform you weather the username and password are correct or wrong.

Same process for other system OpenId, Google.